# Set two variables from function that return two variables or return None

Tags: python-3.x, function, return

1 function:

```
def first_func():
    x = input('Tell me')
    if x == 'q':
        y, z = 5, 5
        return y, z
    if x == 'w':
        y, z = 6, 6
        return y, z
    else:
        print('Nothing for you')
        run_other_function()
        return None
```

I want the user to be able to answer both q, w but also what ever letter the user wants, and then I want to use this function with two variables:

```
r, t = first_func()
```

But if the x is not q or w, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Which I fully understand why I get, but is there anyway to use it like this, or I can't use it at all like this? Can my function return anything in the else, so that r and t don't get a NoneType object?

I want to use r and t as input in another function:

```
coordinates(r,t)
```

But if user inputs anything else then r and t, it will break even before I get there.

Ok, I understand now that this question might be very hard to understand, I might need to re-write it, so everything can be understood.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to raise an exception instead of returning `None`. This will make it clear for the calling code if the call succeeded or not. If it did, then the return type is always a two-tuple.

```
def first_func():
    x = input('Tell me')
    if x == 'q':
        y, z = 5, 5
        return y, z
    if x == 'w':
        y, z = 5, 5
        return y, z
    else:
        print('Nothing for you')
        run_other_function()
        raise ValueError

try:
    r, t = first_function()
except ValueError:
    print('we know for sure something bad happened')
else:
    print('nothing bad happened, we know for sure both r and t are defined and not None')
    print(r, t)
```

If you don't like this approach, you can `return None, None` instead of `return None`. This way `r` and `t` will both be `None`, but then any calling code will need to check if `r` and/or `t` are integers or `None`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the user to be able to use q and w but also what ever, but the q and w will be variables to be used in another function, but if user uses anything but q and w, I dont want the variable to be used in the second function, any thing but q and w should break the program and exit, all this is in a while loop. I do hope I make myself understandable :-)

Comment: @ejohalj not really

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting two results, but you are returning only one.
Try following small change.

```
def first_func():
    x = input('Tell me')
    if x == 'q':
        y, z = 5, 5
        return y, z
    if x == 'w':
        y, z = 6, 6
        return y, z
    else:
        print('Nothing for you')
        run_other_function()
        return None, None
```